# statically adding directives in blade template

Tags: php, laravel-blade

I am using a [Blade template](http://duncan3dc.github.io/blade) for core PHP by [Craig Duncan](https://github.com/duncan3dc) and I wanted to add more directives, so far I tried to add them dynamically and it works fine, my question is there a way I can add more directives statically.

The main aim is to add a predefined path for stylesheets, the default directory for stylesheet is `/css` and `/js` respectively, but my directory for stylesheets is `/assets/css` and `/assets/js`

Here is the Dynamic Implementation

```php
use duncan3dc\Laravel\BladeInstance;
use duncan3dc\Laravel\Directives;
$directives = (new Directives) ->withCss('assets/css') ->withJs('assets/js');
$blade = new BladeInstance("views", "cache/views", $directives);
```

if I was to use the `@css(style)` or `@js(style)` in the blade file then it would compile to the below code, which is the output I want

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" href="/assets/js/style.js"></script>
```

If anyone has any idea how I could implement the above code statically, I would highly appreciate it, Thank you

**NOTE: `This has nothing to do with laravel, am using core PHP`**

Answer (score 0):

You could use your dynamic way and then set it as static instance, for example like this:

```php
use duncan3dc\Laravel\BladeInstance;
use duncan3dc\Laravel\Directives;
use duncan3dc\Laravel\Blade;

$directives = (new Directives) ->withCss('assets/css') ->withJs('assets/js');
$blade = new BladeInstance("views", "cache/views", $directives);
Blade::setInstance($blade);
// then whenever later you can call
Blade::getInstance(); // instead creating new one or passing it around
```

There is also method `Blade::directive` but its parameters require "expanded" directives.

You could do for example:

```php
use duncan3dc\Laravel\Blade;

Blade::directive('css', function($parameter){
    return "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/assets/css/{$parameter}'>";
});
```

But clearly you would loose the advantage of `assetify`, for example: `@css("http://external.source/file.css")` would fail miserably.

So because [Directives->assetify](https://github.com/duncan3dc/blade/blob/7d7e77289c5dfda1dda2da27e5bd1823d2dd42b7/src/Directives.php#L193) is private you could copy its code (which could be public and static but isn't for some reason, don't ask me why) and use static only approach, for example:

```php
use duncan3dc\Laravel\Blade;

function assetify(string $file, string $type, string $path): string
{
    ... // insert Directives->assetify code
}

Blade::directive('css', function($parameter){
    $file = assetify($parameter, "css", 'assets/css');
    return "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='{$file}'>";
});

Blade::directive('js', function($parameter){
    $file = assetify($parameter, "js", 'assets/js');
    return "<script type='text/javascript' src='{$file}'></script>";
});

// then using instance when you need it
Blade::getInstance();
```

Or you could use reflection to bypass the access rights, for example:

```php
use duncan3dc\Laravel\Directives;

function assetify(string $file, string $type, string $path): string
{
    static $assetify;
    if(!$assetify){
        $assetify = new ReflectionMethod(Directives::class, 'assetify');
        $assetify->setAccessible(true);
    }
    return $assetify->invoke(new Directives, $file, $type, $path);
}
```

This way you can be sure that you use the current version.